# Return class derived from generic constraint from a task

Tags: c#, user-interface, generics, async-await

I have created a Generic Task Interface

```
public interface ICalcLoaderTask
{   
    Task<T> Execute<T>(BaseTaskParameters taskParams, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where T : CalcLoaderTaskResult;
}
```

And a class derived from CalcLoaderTaskResult

```
public class CopyNMStoreResult : CalcLoaderTaskResult
{
    public string NMStoreResultsFilePath { get; set; }
}
```

In my implementation of ICalcLoaderClass, I cannot figure out a way to return the results class

```
public async Task<T> Execute<T>(BaseTaskParameters taskParams, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where T : CalcLoaderTaskResult
    {
        var copyFileTaskParams = (CopyFilesTaskParameters)taskParams;
        var GlobalNMStoreResultsFilePath = string.Format("{0}\\WhateverTheFileNameIs.xls", copyFileTaskParams.GlobalShareFolderPath);
        var LocalNMStoreResultsFilePath = string.Format("{0}\\WhateverTheFileNameIs.xls", copyFileTaskParams.GlobalShareFolderPath);

        await FileUtility.CopyFileAsync(GlobalNMStoreResultsFilePath, LocalNMStoreResultsFilePath, cancellationToken);

        var result = new CopyNMStoreResult
        {
            NMStoreResultsFilePath = GlobalNMStoreResultsFilePath
        };
        return result; //Cannot implicitly convert type
    }
```

How do I return thisresult? Or is my pattern incorrect? I will be re-using this type of pattern with different return types derived from CalcLoaderTaskResult. CalcLoaderTaskResult is abstract

Comment: Your function does not return a `Task` nor an object of type `T`. Why have the two instead of just `CopyNMStoreResult` or `CalcLoaderTaskResult` as the return type?

Comment: If you want the method to only return one specific type, then don't make it generic; making the method generic is indicating that the caller can provide whatever type they want to indicate what should be returned.

Comment: I wanted to create a re-usable interface. I need to repeat this pattern 25 times and wanted a common interface to execute the tasks. The return types will be different, but all derived from CalcLoaderTaskResult

Comment: @FrankM That's all well and good, but you've defined an interface that says that each implementing method has a method where *the caller of that method* defines what it's return type is, so it needs to honor that.  If these implementations can't do that, then you need to adjust the interface to define something that they *can* implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your implementation always returns an object of the same type, I would formulate the interface differently

```
public interface ICalcLoaderTask<T>
    where T : CalcLoaderTaskResult
{   
    Task<T> Execute(BaseTaskParameters taskParams, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
}
```

I.e. the type (interface) is generic instead of the method.

And then let your implementation implement the concrete type

```
public class MyImplementation : ICalcLoaderTask<CopyNMStoreResult>
{
    public async Task<CopyNMStoreResult> Execute(BaseTaskParameters taskParams,
                                                 CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ...
        var result = new CopyNMStoreResult
        {
            NMStoreResultsFilePath = GlobalNMStoreResultsFilePath
        };
        return result;
    }
}
```

Because the caller cannot choose the type of the return value anyway.

It is technically possible to let the the generic type parameter open

```
public class MyImplementation<T> : ICalcLoaderTask<T> where T ...
```

but since the return type of your method is hard-coded, there is no advantage in doing so.

---

Note: It is possible to let a method return different types. Adding the generic type constraint `new` allows you to create an object with `new T()`. The constraint `new` means that the type `T` must have a default constructor.

```
T MyMethod<T>()
    where T : MyBase, new
{
    return new T();
}
```

Comment: That worked. It's been a while since I've had to write TAP. Trying to implement a standard pattern for the other devs to follow because there will be 20 or 30 similar tasks with different return types all derived from a base return type. Thanks, that helped.